# How do I export the data from the windows powershell into excel with only the LISTEN/ESTABLISHED column?

Tags: powershell

I am only trying to graph 30-second intervals of strings LISTEN, ESTABLISHED with windows powershell.. There are four columns, and I am getting the data every 30 seconds.. The transcript gives me a txt document with three columns I do not need.. Where can I separate how many LISTEN/ESTABLISHED are in 30 seconds intervals to make a graph? Do I need to put in my command to not show the first three columns and only look for LISTEN ESTABLISHED every 30 seconds?

the cmds I used:

```
start-transcript

netstat -na 30 | select-string LISTEN,ESTABLISHED

stop-transcript
```

Comment: Does this mean you're manually stopping the script via `ctrl + c`? I would recommend the use of `Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen,Established` instead.

Comment: Yeah that's what I am doing, with that command though, I would need to record it every 30 seconds, so do I have to manually enter it every 30 seconds?

Comment: No, use a loop. `while ($true) { Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen,Established; sleep 30 }` The difference isn't only just the speed, but the structure of the output. Compared to `netstat`, you would be working with objects rather than text.

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: getting it in a csv file, to graph the qualitative data of how many listen & established over 30 second intervals

Comment: So you don't care about any of the other properties and just want a csv that displays the total amount of `Listening`, and `Established` connections?

Comment: That is true because I need to graph that.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution would be to use a `try` and `finally` block since it will run the code inside `finally {...}` when the command is halted via `ctrl + c`:

```
try {
    while ($true)
    {
        $connections += Get-NetTCPConnection -State 'Established','Listen'
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30
    }
}
finally {
    $(
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Established = $connections.Where{$_.State -eq 'Established'}.Count
            Listening   = $connections.Where{$_.State -eq 'Listen'}.Count
        }
    ) | Out-Default
}
```

Appending to `$connections` we will save the results returned from `Get-NetTCPConnection` until you terminate the indefinite `while ($true)` loop. This allows the use of it outside our loop to be reference inside the `finally` block. `Out-Default` is needed in this case due to `ctrl + c` halting further output to the pipeline and it will force it out.

The above returns the the below output:

```
Listening Established
--------- -----------
       14          32
```

---

*If you want to export to a csv file, you can substitute `Out-Default` for `Export-Csv -Path 'C:\My\Path\csv.csv' -NoTypeInformation`.*